# Getting exit code -1073741515 when running Qt application in CLion

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get Qt to work in my CLion project, but I am having some trouble. I installed Qt using the Qt online installer and I tried following the tutorial on their website (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html).
This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(Chess)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:\\Libraries\\Qt\\6.6.1\\mingw_64\\lib\\cmake")

find_package(Qt6Widgets REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

add_executable(Chess
        main.cpp
        src/game/headers/board.h
        src/game/board.cpp
        src/game/headers/piece.h
        src/utils/headers/util.h
        src/game/headers/move.h
        src/game/headers/boardState.h
        src/moveGeneration/headers/moveGenerator.h
        src/moveGeneration/moveGenerator.cpp
        src/engines/headers/counter.h
        src/engines/headers/engine.h
        src/engines/headers/random.h
        src/engines/headers/greedy.h
        src/utils/headers/zobrist.h
        src/utils/zobrist.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Chess PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)
```

This is my main file that I had ChatGPT make for me, since I have no experience with Qt and just wanted to make sure everything works.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "HERE";
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Create a QWidget (window)
    QWidget window;

    // Create a QPushButton (button)
    auto *button = new QPushButton("Click me!", &window);

    // Connect the button click event to a slot (function)
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
        // Show a message box when the button is clicked
        QMessageBox::information(&window, "Message", "Button clicked!");
    });

    // Set the layout for the window
    auto *layout = new QVBoxLayout(&window);
    layout->addWidget(button);

    // Set up the main window
    window.setLayout(layout);
    window.setWindowTitle("Qt Hello World");
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200);
    window.show();

    // Enter the Qt event loop
    return app.exec();
}
```

This builds fine, but when I try to run it, "HERE" doesn't even get printed. Instead, I just get this message

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

From what I understand, this means that some dll's aren't found. I possible solution someone suggested on a different question was adding D:\Libraries\Qt\6.6.1\mingw_64\bin (in my case) to the path variable. This however didn't fix it for me.

I have no idea why this doesn't work and I have been struggling with this for some time now. Help would be greatly appreciated. I would be happy to offer more information if needed.

Comment: `0xC0000135` means dll not found. [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xC0000135](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xC0000135)

Comment: You can use this program to figure out what dlls that you are missing: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: And this to help understand how your OS finds the dependent dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-unpackaged-apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-unpackaged-apps)

Comment: Also if you set the `PATH` environment variable the change does not effect already running processes (like your IDE or windows explorer) or their children. You may want to logout then login to get it to happen. And on top of that an IDE may have its own `PATH`  settings that override the system.

Comment: @drescherjm yeah, massive brain fart on my part. I added the thing to path, but I didn't restart my IDE. It does work, thanks a lot <3

Comment: You may want to either self answer the question or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the thing to the path does solve the issue, I just didn't restart my IDE.

Comment: Exercise caution adding stuff to the path. You need to make sure the stuff you add doesn't result in duplication of DLLs with different versions. If a tool finds the matching DLLs for a different tool before it finds its own, the results can be confusing as hell.